# PHP MYSQL UPDATE DATE column with input type date?

Tags: php, mysql

Just a simple DATE with an input type Date and I want to UPDATE a DATE column in MySQL WITH PHP. (I SEE LOTS OF ANSWERS FOR DATETIME, I JUST WANT TO INSERT DATE LIKE: '1980-07-23')

```
$dobdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $_POST["dob"])));
$dob = $DBConnection->quote($dobdate);
$sql = "UPDATE `userinfo` SET dob = ? WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $DBConnection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$dob, $_SESSION["id"]]);
```

My dob column is only getting: 0000-00-00

Answer (score 0):

Try This it works for me

```
    $dobdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $_POST["date"])));
    $sql = $DBConnection->prepare("UPDATE userinfo SET dob=:dob WHERE id=:id");
    $sql->execute([
      'dob' => $dobdate,
       'id'=>$_SESSION["id"]
    ]);
```

or remove this line

```
$dob = $DBConnection->quote($dobdate);
```